# SQL Plus How to only display rows if it does not have two different results for the same account

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sqlplus

I was hoping someone could help with only showing accounts if it only modified by user_name = 'system'

Example table_1

```
ID
USER_NAME
DATE_TIME
UPDATES
```

Lets say I do

```
select * from table_1 where ID='14'
ID        USER_NAME              UPDATES
14         system              deleted record
14         system              updated record
14         system              updated record
14         system              copied record
```

and lets say I do

```
select * from table_1 where ID='26'
ID        USER_NAME            UPDATES
26         system              updated record
26         system              deleted record
26         Michael             updated record
26         system              updated record
```

I am basically trying to create a query where if there is anything other than 'system', don't show any records for that ID.  So, for the example in the output above, I don't want any row of ID 26 to show (even the ones that were updated by the system) because one of the records was updated by something other than 'system'. I only want ID 14 to show since all records were updated by the user_name 'system'

final output should look something like
ID
14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists` or `not in` if you want the detail:

```
select t.*
from table_1 t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_1 tt
                  where tt.id = t.id and tt.user_name <> 'system'
                 );
```

If you just want the `id`, then use `group by`:

```
select t.id
from table_1 t
group by t.id
having sum(t.user_name = 'system') = count(*);  -- all rows have `system`
```

Note:  You can also use `having sum(t.user_name <> 'system') = 0`.  However, the two handle `NULL` values subtly differently.

Comment: Thank you! The first query worked perfect, exactly what I trying to do. The second one I was getting a "missing right parentheses" error.

Comment: @connollyc4 . . . The second should work in MySQL -- as the question is tagged.  However, it won't work in Oracle, which is suggested by SQLPlus.